# Python is not recognizing null in a list

Tags: python, list, null, numbers, syntax-error

I am new in Python and I have a question. What should I put in line 5? I want to see if the character c doesn't exist in groups, then I want to create one and assign it to 0. And then, increase it as much as this character has appeared

```
def firstUniqChar(self, s):

    groups = {}
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
        c = s[i]
        if groups[c] == null:
            groups[c] = 0
        else:
            groups[c] = groups[c] + 1
    for j in range(0, len(s) - 1):
        if groups[s[i]] == 1:
            return j
    return -1
```

Comment: `c not in groups`? Or `groups.get(c) is None` - Python doesn't have `null`.

Comment: `groups[c]` for nonexistant `c` key  will throw an error. Use `groups.get(c, None)` instead to default to None if key c not exissts

Comment: `groups.get(c)` will return `None` by default, if the key does not exist.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Answer (score -3):

Rather than null you need to write None in python.

You can write it like

```
if groups[c] is None:
```

Comment: if c not in groups -> Exception

Comment: Than you have to handle the exception. You can look up for try except. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: You miss the point - the whole post is about `c` NOT being in groups and then to add it as new key with a count of 0.